# Как пользоваться namespace?

Tags: php, namespace, ооп

Структура сайта такова:

- /
- /core
- /core/connect.php
- /core/read.php
- /index.php

Насколько я понял, `namespace` позволяет смотреть в нужную директорию относительно корневой директории.
В итоге,есть два файла.
[read.php](http://pastebin.com/17NY25rw)
[connect.php](http://pastebin.com/Pfr7RQEB)
Connect находится в `namespace core`, что показывается папкой.По идее, `read` тоже находится в `namespace core`, но если я пишу ему этот `namespace`, то `phpstorm` показывает, что строчка

```
$connection=connect::connect();
```

ошибочна,т.к. нет параметра `$db_host`. Если убрать `namespace` то ошибка исчезает. Почему так?
P.S. можно забить конечно, ошибку ведь не показывает,но напрягает непонимание происходящего.Спасибо заранее за разъяснения!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> namespace позволяет смотреть в нужную директорию

*Нет, но да.* Namespace сам по себе определяет область, в которой существуют классы/константы/функции, не имея никакой зависимости от папки, в которой лежит файл, и от собственного названия файла. Однако если не следовать конвенции наименования (если очень грубо - папки называются по неймспейсам), то процедура автозагрузки файлов заметно усложняется, а это, в общем-то, самый простой способ подтягивать при запросе исключительно те файлы, которые нужны. Почитать конвенцию можно в стандарте [PSR-4](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-4-autoloader.md) и [PSR-0](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md).

> но если я пишу ему этот namespace,то phpstorm показывает,что строчка ... ошибочна

потому что если они в одном неймспейсе, то PHPStorm видит, что у метода есть обязательный параметр $db_host, в противном случае он ничего не выводит, потому что не знает о компоненте, который вы пытаетесь вызвать; так как PHP не очень строгий язык и в нем есть поддержка многочисленных автозагрузчиков, PHPStorm не может сам определить, существует компонент или же он просто не виден для PHPStorm'a. *(ну, точнее сказать, я думаю, что логика именно такова)*

Comment: понял,namespace как раз предупредил меня о неправильном написании функции.Спасибо за пояснение.

Answer (score 0):

Namespace указывается вначале файла, и все что ниже работает в этом пространстве имен. Авто-загрузчик composer`a  ищет классы в каталогах и файлах согласно указанному в нем стандарту psr0/4/етцетра. Если вы делаете загрузку файлов классов самостоятельным загрузчиком, то даже сложенные в одну папку, подгрузятся все классы, и все файлы, и по идее будут доступны. Но это в свою очередь может усложнить отладку и понимание того где и что находится, а также все классы и файлы в которых они находятся будут обязаны иметь уникальные имена даже если они делают что то идентичное.